# GitHub Pages images not loading

Tags: html, css, image, github, github-pages

I have a website that I am developing. It's currently hosted on GitHub pages for Dev purposes. KevinRanke.github.io

The main image with alt text of "IRS" is not loading and I don't know why. Any ideas? Naming convention wrong? IMG tag having the wrong class attribute? Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: FYI. I am using the "Foundation" framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLs are case sensitive. In your HTML, you are linking to the image:

https://kevinranke.github.io/images/skillet.jpg

Whereas in your repository, the extension is capitalized:

https://kevinranke.github.io/images/skillet.JPG

Comment: So how do I fix it then? It works fine when I run it locally. Isn't my HTML the same as what is in my repo?

Comment: @Kevin Ether change your HTML to use the uppercase extension, or rename your image to use the lowercase extension. My guess is that it works locally because you're on a case insensitive filesystem; this is not the case on GitHub's servers.

Comment: Perfect. I will try that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

.PNG files are saved with capitals (.PNG) this is why some of my images loaded (.jpeg) and some didn't (the.PNG files didn't load because i wrote them as .png in my html)